# playing sound on if statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, audio

I am looking for a way to play a sound on an if-statement.

To be exact. I want a sound to be automatically played, when the amount of attempts have reached 3.

Is there a way to get this to work?

```js
// guesses
function testbutton() {
  attempt++;
  document.getElementById("alarm").innerHTML = "guess" + attempt;
}

// guess set to zero
var attempt = 0;

// sound functions
if (attempt == 3) {
  var sound20 = new Audio('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Collision8-Bit.ogg');
  var playSound = function() {
    sound20.play();
  }
};

playSound();
```

```html
<button onclick="testbutton();">Test</button>

<p id="alarm"></p>
```

Comment: where is the java code ?

Comment: The `if` statement should be inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `if` statement inside the function, after you increment `attempt`.

```js
// guesses
function testbutton() {
  attempt++;
  document.getElementById("alarm").innerHTML = "guess" + attempt;
  if (attempt == 3) {
    playSound();
  };
}

// guess set to zero
var attempt = 0;

// sound functions
var playSound = function() {
  var sound20 = new Audio('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Collision8-Bit.ogg');
  sound20.play();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testbutton();">Test</button>

<p id="alarm"></p>
```